# How to pass string variable as parameter to awk

Tags: command-line, scripts, awk

I have following command:

```
usb_soundcard_sink=$(pactl list short sinks | grep "alsa_output" | awk '{ print $2 }' | tail -n1)
```

output of this command is:

```
alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
```

And this is another command that find index number:

```
var=$(pactl list short sinks | awk '$2=="alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo" {print $1}')
```

output:

```
0
```

But I want pass the "usb_soundcard_sink" variable instead of hard coded value i.e. "alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo" in above command. b'coz value of "usb_soundcard_sink" variable may change dynamically.

Also I tried the following:

```
var=$(pactl list short sinks | awk '$2=="$usb_soundcard_sink" {print $1}')
```

But it is not working

so how can I pass value of "usb_soundcard_sink" variable to the above command

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To pass a  inside into your awk code, you have to use the `-v` syntax like this:

```
$ awk -v myvar="3" 'BEGIN{print myvar}'
#     \__________/              \___/          
3
```

In your specific case, just use:

```bash
pactl list short sinks | awk -v myvar="$usb_soundcard_sink" '$2==myvar {print $1}'
#                               \___/                            \___/
#                                 |________________________________|
```

Comment: If you want to pass two variables, make sure to repeat the -v switch, like echo | awk -v myVar1=12 -v myVar2="${usb_soundcard_sink}" '...'

Answer (score 5):

I found that this works too

```
line=myfile.dat
f=8
s=11
echo $line | awk '{print $'$f',$'$s'}'
```

Here I have a file called myfile.dat piped into awk which spits out column 8 and 11.

Comment: Sorry. Bad solution. Unreadable awk script :-(

Answer (score 0):

Both MAWK (Ubuntu's default AWK version) and GAWK read non-option command line arguments in the form `identifier=value` as variable assignments, which are performed right after the `BEGIN` statements have been executed:

```
% echo | mawk -- '{print var}' var=foo 
foo
% echo | gawk -- '{print var}' var=foo
foo
% echo foo bar baz | mawk -- '{$1=$1}1' OFS=,
foo,bar,baz
% echo foo bar baz | gawk -- '{$1=$1}1' OFS=,
foo,bar,baz
```

I prefer this method to the `-v` option because it keeps the command cleaner, clearly separating the options to be passed to the interpreter and the program's details.

From `man mawk`:

> The command line arguments divide into three sets: file arguments, assignment arguments and empty strings "". An assignment has the form var=string. When an ARGV[i] is examined as a possible file argument, if it is empty it is skipped; if it is an assignment argument, the assignment to var takes place and i skips to the next argument; else ARGV[i] is opened for input.

From `man gawk`:

> If a filename on the command line has the form var=val it is treated as a variable assignment. The variable var will be assigned the value val. (This happens after any BEGIN rule(s) have been run.) Command line variable assignment is most useful for dynamically assigning values to the variables AWK uses to control how input is broken into fields and records. It is also useful for controlling state if multiple passes are needed over a single data file.